# Fixing phase unwrapping errors in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, phase

I have a series of unwrapped phases, with some unwrapping errors that consist of a jump of +/- a multiple of Pi:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([0.5, 1.3, 2.4, 10.3, 10.8, 10.2, 7.6, 3.2, 2.9])
```

In this example there is a first jump of 2 cycles between 2.4 and 10.3, and a jump of -1 cycle between 7.6 and 3.2. I want to remove the jumps. The catch is that when you remove a jump, you need to increase or decrease the rest of the series accordingly, not just the value where the jump occurs.

Is there a cleaner way (no/less loops, faster) of doing this:

```
jumpsexist = 1
while jumpsexist:
    # Look for absolute differences greater than Pi
    jump = numpy.abs((numpy.roll(a,-1) -a)) > numpy.pi
    if jump[:-1].any():
        # Find the index of the first jump
        jumpind = numpy.argmax(jump) + 1
        # Calculate the number of cycles in that jump
        cycles = ((a[jumpind] - a[jumpind- 1]) / numpy.pi).astype("Int8")
        # Remove the cycles
        a[jumpind:] -= cycles * numpy.pi
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Note that the variable is not called "jump sexist", but "jumps exist". I'll take "s words" for 200.

Comment: In keeping with your poorly chosen variable names, you might find the numpy function `cumsum` to be useful here. That's cumulative sum not ... nevermind.

Comment: On a side note, phase unwrapping in the presence of noise is an open research problem... You wouldn't happen to be working on InSAR data, would you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NumPy offers the function `numpy.unwrap()` for phase unwrapping.  With the default parameter values, it will correct an array of phases modulo 2π such that all jumps are less than or equal to π:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([0.5, 1.3, 2.4, 10.3, 10.8, 10.2, 7.6, 3.2, 2.9])
>>> numpy.unwrap(a)
array([ 0.5       ,  1.3       ,  2.4       ,  4.01681469,  4.51681469,
        3.91681469,  1.31681469,  3.2       ,  2.9       ])
```

Comment: Changed this to accepted answer. Although not clear in my original question, this is really what I was after.

Comment: @Benjamin: I was suspecting you are – that's why I was pressing you to state your requirements clearly. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([0.5, 1.3, 2.4, 10.3, 10.8, 10.2, 7.6, 3.2, 2.9])
d = np.diff(a)/np.pi
b = np.empty_like(a)
b[0] = a[0]
b[1:] = a[1:]-(np.floor(np.abs(d))*np.sign(d)).cumsum()*np.pi
```

which gives:

```
In [40]: print a
[  0.5   1.3   2.4  10.3  10.8  10.2   7.6   3.2   2.9]

In [41]: print b
[ 0.5         1.3         2.4         4.01681469  4.51681469  3.91681469
  1.31681469  0.05840735 -0.24159265]
```

Here `d` holds the signed magntiude of the "jumps", and cumulative summation of the appropriately truncated "jumps" is the mulitple of pi which needs to be removed/added to each sucessive element of the series.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Right on. For readability, `d = (numpy.diff(phases) / numpy.pi).astype("Int8")` and `b[1:] = a[1:] - numpy.cumsum(d) * numpy.pi ` might be clearer.